# Numpy equivalent of MATLAB's cell array

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I want to create a MATLAB-like cell array in Numpy. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Matlab cell arrays [are most similar](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html#matlab-cell-arrays) to Python lists, since they can hold any object - but scipy.io.loadmat imports them as numpy object arrays - which is an array with dtype=object.

To be honest though you are just as well off using Python lists - if you are holding general objects you will loose almost all of the advantages of numpy arrays (which are designed to hold a sequence of values which each take the same amount of memory).

Comment: The one thing that I am missing by using python lists is the possibility of indexing the array with an array of indexes. Thanks for making me discover numpy object arrays :)

Comment: Possibly the biggest drawback with the 'array of object' approach is that Matlab cells have value semantics: storing an array A into a cell C protects the cell element from changes to A afterwards. Where ndarray with dtype=object will simply store a reference to A, Matlab stores a lazy, copy-on-write _clone_. This difference exists throughout numpy, though. You'll find it when using arrays as function parameters, f.e.