# Python iteration and multi-dimensional array structure

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to store as a variable in a python script, `mxn` arrays using nested loops as follows:

```
A=[ ]
for j in ListA:
   for x in ListB:
      values = some.function(label_fname, stc_fname)
      A(j)=values(x)
```

for each `x`, `values` is an `mxn` matrix with `m~=n`.
When I index values here by `values[x]` or `values(x)` I get: 
`output operand requires a reduction, but reduction is not enabled` OR `can't assign to function call`.

What I would like to due is append `values(x)` matrices and store in `A(j)`. Honestly, I can't say this in English, but in matlab lingo I am trying to create a cell array, where `A{j}` is an `mxn` array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761419/matlab-like-structure-cell-array-in-numpy

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I think the OP is already using `numpy`.  "output operand requires a reduction [etc.]" is a `numpy` error message.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have several issues with python:

1. When indexing into a list, use `[` and `]`; not `(` and `)`. Also, the first element of a list is at index 0. This means that if you have a list `L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],

   - The index of 'a' in L is 0
   - The index of 'b' in L is 1
   - The index of 'c' in L is 2
   - The index of 'd' in L is 3

From what I understand from your explanation, I would suggest the following code. See if it works for you:

```
A = []
for sub_list in ListA:
    temp = []
    for x in ListB:
        values = some.function(label_fname, stc_fname)
        temp.append(values)
    A.append(temp)
```

I'm really not very sure what you are asking for, but hopefully, this is a good start. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying / expecting to create a [`dict()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict)  with `j` as the the key.

Or, for multidimensional arrays, `numpy` is very useful

See the dict() docs: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Note:

```
> A(j) # this calls function A
> A[j] # this returns the list item 'j'
> A[j] = foo # this sets list item 'j' = foo
```