# Creating a numpy array in a particular format

Tags: python, numpy

This is trainData

```
[[-214. -153.  -58. ...,   36.  191.  -37.]
[-139.  -73.   -1. ...,   11.   76.  -14.]
[ -76.  -49. -307. ...,   41.  228.  -41.]
..., 
[ -32.  -49.   49. ...,  -26.  133.  -32.]
[-124.  -79.  -37. ...,   39.  298.   -3.]
[-135. -186.  -70. ...,  -12.  790.  -10.]]
```

This is target

```
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

I want to create a numpy array using trainData and target which looks like this

```
[
 [[-214. -153.  -58. ...,   36.  191.  -37.], [0]]
 [[-139.  -73.   -1. ...,   11.   76.  -14.], [0]]
 [[ -76.  -49. -307. ...,   41.  228.  -41.], [0]]
 ..., 
 [[ -32.  -49.   49. ...,  -26.  133.  -32.], [1]]
 [[-124.  -79.  -37. ...,   39.  298.   -3.], [1]]
 [[-135. -186.  -70. ...,  -12.  790.  -10.], [1]]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Mixing arrays with different shapes requires some compromises.  The normal `array` has constant dimensions all around.

Sample data:

```
In [343]: td = np.arange(20.).reshape(5,4)
In [344]: target=np.arange(5).reshape(5,1)*10
```

You could combine them into one 2d array, by concatenation, adding `target` as an extra column to `td`:

```
In [345]: np.hstack([td,target])
Out[345]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   0.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,  10.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,  20.],
       [ 12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  30.],
       [ 16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  40.]])
```

Something that will appear to be closer to your goal is a structured array.  It is easiest to make an empty one of the right shape, and then fill it with the data

```
In [346]: combine=np.empty((5,),dtype=[('td','f',(4,)),('target','i',(1,))])
```

then fill it field by field

```
In [347]: combine['td']=td
In [348]: combine['target']=target
```

The result:

```
In [349]: combine
Out[349]: 
array([([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [0]), ([4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0], [10]),
       ([8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0], [20]), ([12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0], [30]),
       ([16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0], [40])], 
      dtype=[('td', '<f4', (4,)), ('target', '<i4', (1,))])
```

Note, though, that each 'row' is displayed as `([...].[...])`

The original data can be 'recovered' with `combine['td']` and `combine['target']`.  And an element of the array as `combine[0]`.

But `combine` doesn't do a whole lot for you. You can do math with the fields like `combine['td']*combine['target']`, but you could to that with `td*target`.  You can't do `combine[:2] *= 2`, i.e. act on both fields at once.

Comment: it seems using structured arrays is the way to go here (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe normal `numpy` arrays enforce equal shape in all dimensions, meaning you can't have some entries with greater size than others.  See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761419/matlab-like-structure-cell-array-in-numpy) on the matter.  If you just want to join your two arrays though, you can do that like so:

```
import numpy
trainingData = numpy.array([[-214., -153, -58., 5],[-139, -73, -1, 2]])
target = numpy.array([[0],[1]])
combined = numpy.concatenate((trainingData,target), axis=1)
```

If you really want to keep the target and training data in separate subarrays of different length and have to use numpy, you could just use a numpy object array, e.g.

```
combined = numpy.array(zip(trainingData,target))
```

But really at the point you'd probably just be better off using a python list or some custom container object.